# AngularDart mobile web apps

Tags: angular-dart

Is it possible to create mobile web apps with AngularDart?

Like using: http://mobileangularui.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no specific mobile-focused framework for AngularDart, like http://mobileangularui.com, that I know of.

But it is certainly possible to create small progressive web apps using the standard AngularDart framework. There is even an example of one in the AngularDart repository - https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/tree/master/examples/hacker_news_pwa